# Determining an unknown parameter in an equation with modular arithmetics

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Consider a machine which takes $x$ and $y$ as input, and gives $z$ as an output  using the following equation:

$z =\left[(x + k) \mod l\right] \oplus \left[(y + k) \mod l\right].$

$x, y, z, k,$ and $l$ are positive integers. $l$ is a public value and known. $k$ is unknown. We can feed this machine by $x$ and $y$, and observe output $z$.

How can we determine $k$ using input $x$ and $y$, and output $z$? How many pairs of input/output is required to uniquely determine $k$?